# How to use the phrase "via the form of"

Tags: word-usage

This is my sentence:
As you can guess from the name of my company, it focuses on providing supports to SMEs including financial support (via the form of preferential loans) and technical supports (via the form of training, consulting and business matching).
Do you think "via the form of..." is proper English? If not, is there any other ways?

Comment: Maybe ***via*** isn't actually "ungrammatical" (though I'd like to hope it is! :) But in practice I think almost everyone would use ***in** the form of preferential loans.*

Comment: People really seem to love the word "via" recently, don't they. All the cool, trendy, "intelligent" people say "via," apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that unless the "**via**"-thing is really popular with the people in Marketing, it would make for smoother and simpler speech/text if you just replaced the word (in your examples) with "**in**".

"**Via the..**" is actually redundant.  If you want to say something using "**the form of**" ("*in* the form of", "*it takes* the form of", etc.), don't use "**via**", and instead you can just use "**in**" or whatever. :)

If, instead, you *did* want to use "**via**", then I suggest things like the following: "**via preferential loans**", or alternately you *could* use "***as* preferential loans**", but I actually prefer "**via**" there.

Hm actually, I'll just copy-edit your question below (it just fixes a few minor grammar bits)!  Here's your question, edited by me:

---

> As you can guess from the name of my company, it focuses on providing **support** to SMEs **,***("<- add comma")* including financial support (**via preferential loans**) and technical **support** (**in the form of** training, consulting and business matching). Do you think "via the form of..." is proper English? If not, **are** there any other ways?

There you go — the first one uses "**via**", the second "**in the form of**", along with a couple tiny singular-vs-plural changes :)   Hope maybe that helps some — cheers!